# Implementing Heap's algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I am trying to implement [Heap's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) in C++. I feel I have written the code exactly as the algorithm works but it is giving wrong results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> v)

{ 
   for(auto x:v) 
            cout<<x;
   cout<<endl;
}

void gen(vector<int> v,int n)

{  
      if(v.size()==1) 
          cout<<v[0];
      print(v);
      int i = 0;
      while(i<n)
       {
          gen(v,n-1);
          if(n%2) 
               swap(v[n-1],v[0]);
          else 
               swap(v[n-1],v[i]);
          i++;
       }

}


int main()
{
  vector<int>  v  ={1,2,3};
  gen(v,v.size());
}
```

I am stuck at trying to make this work. 
For the vector in the above code, it gives the absurd result:

123
123
123
123
213
213
321
321
321
231
231
123
123
123
213
213

Comment: You probably didn't want `gen(vector<int> v,int n)` to pass `v` by-value, did you?

Comment: Considering that the function itself prints the results, that's less stupid than it looks at first sight.

Comment: @WhozCraig am i doing the passing wrong ?

Comment: @MSalters would be grateful if you could help however stupid it may be. I am stuck here.

Comment: @edbale I was just asking. Was your intent that `gen` *modify* the caller's vector? If so, yes, you're doing it wrong. If no, then no.

Comment: @WhozCraig no didn't want the original vector to be modified.

Comment: @edbale then its fine as-is (the parameter passing, anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wiki page shows an `if-else` that's missing from your code. The one `if` that you have does something completely different.

Also, I'd add a `std::endl` after the cout, and try with the input `1 2 3 4`. The linked article has a line-by-line example of the algorithm running for 4 elements.

Comment: that i think won't matter as it is just a check for single element vector which has only one permutation.

Comment: @edbale it actually matters a great deal, since your code checks `v.size()` against `1`, which it will *never* be.  You're passing a 3-element vector in to this and doing *nothing* to change that. Pretty sure that `v.size()` should be `n`. Once that is done the `else` becomes *very* relevant.

Comment: @edbale: That's where you misunderstood. Check the example on the right side of the page. The print call happens **if and only if**  `n=1`. Since you need 6 permutations, you should have 6 calls to `gen(v,1)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes its wrong it should be n, but still i don't know how mr MSalters could call this question so stupid but yet mr Craig i can't get it working

Comment: @WhozCraig: For `n==1`, you should print more than just `v[0]`. The actual `print(v)` function is correct, it's just called far too often.

Comment: @edbale and for the record, he didn't say the question was stupid; he said the output **you** said was "absurd" was *less* stupid than i looks at first sight.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, that is exactly where I had misunderstood, thanks a lot.  would u please upvote my question or else I will be banned from asking more questions. I am improving though.

Comment: @MSalters And now the code fails for a 5 element vector ? It works for 3 ,4 element vector but fails for 5. How can this happen ?

Comment: @edbale: The best way to deal with that is to fix the question yourself. What output should the program produce? In particular, in which order? Try running the algorithm manually, on paper.

Comment: @MSalters sir, I run the same code with gen taking arg as a reference and not value and the program worked correctly. I don't get why passigng by value was wrong and if it was wrong how can it give correct results for length 3 and 5 arrays.

Comment: @edbale: pass-by-value makes unnecessary copies. That's wrong in an engineering sense, but correct in an algorithmic sense.